# Isotope not displaying items in firefox 4

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-isotope

I've been using isotope to set up a filterable library of publications and it's working fine in all browsers except firefox as far as I can see.

I've set up a jsfiddle here (obviously view in firefox to see it not working!):
http://jsfiddle.net/bellamystudio/wfz5N/

There's nothing in firebug to indicate there's an error, and isotope seems to work fine for firefox on the isotope website (isotope.metafizzy.co), so I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong! Can anyone see a problem with my code?

Any help much appreciated as always!

Comment: Lots of views but no ideas yes - perhaps I haven't been helpful enough with my post to enable anyone to help me - if there's anything else I can say or explain relating to this issue to enable someone to help me please let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a floating issue adding

```
#library { clear: both; }
```

did the trick.  See http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/wfz5N/1/

Comment: Desandro, you are a deity. Thank you *so* much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was having the exact same issues.